# Spring Boot / Hibernate Select's before insert

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I'm trying to insert a row in the following table, Hibernate does a `SELECT` before each insert and I'd like to avoid that. I think that Hibernate does this `SELECT` before the insert to see if that object is new or not. That's why I have implemented `Persistable` interface and I have overridden the methods of this.
The entity has combine id.

```
select groupreleq0_.equipment_id as equipmen3_22_0_, groupreleq0_.program_group_id as program_4_22_0_, groupreleq0_.description as descript1_22_0_, groupreleq0_.quantity as quantity2_22_0_ from group_m2m_equipment groupreleq0_ where groupreleq0_.equipment_id=? and groupreleq0_.program_group_id=?
select groupreleq0_.equipment_id as equipmen3_22_0_, groupreleq0_.program_group_id as program_4_22_0_, groupreleq0_.description as descript1_22_0_, groupreleq0_.quantity as quantity2_22_0_ from group_m2m_equipment groupreleq0_ where groupreleq0_.equipment_id=? and groupreleq0_.program_group_id=?
select groupreleq0_.equipment_id as equipmen3_22_0_, groupreleq0_.program_group_id as program_4_22_0_, groupreleq0_.description as descript1_22_0_, groupreleq0_.quantity as quantity2_22_0_ from group_m2m_equipment groupreleq0_ where groupreleq0_.equipment_id=? and groupreleq0_.program_group_id=?
select groupreleq0_.equipment_id as equipmen3_22_0_, groupreleq0_.program_group_id as program_4_22_0_, groupreleq0_.description as descript1_22_0_, groupreleq0_.quantity as quantity2_22_0_ from group_m2m_equipment groupreleq0_ where groupreleq0_.equipment_id=? and groupreleq0_.program_group_id=?
insert into group_m2m_equipment (description, quantity, equipment_id, program_group_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
insert into group_m2m_equipment (description, quantity, equipment_id, program_group_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
insert into group_m2m_equipment (description, quantity, equipment_id, program_group_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
insert into group_m2m_equipment (description, quantity, equipment_id, program_group_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class GroupEquipmentPK implements Serializable {

    protected Long programGroupId;
    protected Long equipmentId;

}
```

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "group_m2m_equipment")
public class GroupRelEquipment implements Serializable, Persistable<GroupEquipmentPK> {

    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupEquipmentPK groupEquipmentPK = new GroupEquipmentPK();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JsonIgnore
    @MapsId("equipmentId")
    private Equipment equipment;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JsonIgnore
    @MapsId("programGroupId")
    private ProgramGroup programGroup;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "quantity ")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true;

    public GroupRelEquipment(GroupEquipmentPK groupEquipmentPK, Equipment equipment, ProgramGroup programGroup, String description, Integer quantity) {
        this.groupEquipmentPK = groupEquipmentPK;
        this.equipment = equipment;
        this.programGroup = programGroup;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


    @Override
    public GroupEquipmentPK getId() {
        return this.groupEquipmentPK;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate does a SELECT query before the INSERT to check if this value is already exists... I found a solution for that by calling EntityManager object and use .persist() method insteed .save() and that's how I avoided those SELECTS

Answer (score -1):

Yes that's how JPA does updates. There is not an update method.

I suggest you let it execute the select queries if you do not execute saves too often.

Comment: No that is not how JPA does updates, for regular updates it will just execute an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Yes it will do an update query after it verifies that the data already exist.

Comment: No it doesn't, it has other ways (based on the type of PK) to determine if it is an existing one or not.

Comment: I am speaking about Insertion .. That's means that I'm speaking about new Objects and not to update olds...
Hibernate does a SELECT query before the INSERT to check if this value is already exists... I found a solution for that by calling EntityManager object and use .persist() method insteed .save() and that's how I avoided those SELECTS